# jquery mobile google maps showing intermittently

Tags: html, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

Hi guys after fixing one problem with the project I'm working on I've hit another on, now I know this question as been asked quite a good few times but the solutions I have found don't seem to make a difference.

So I'm basically trying to integrate a get directions kind of function into my app, which I have basically taken from the demos of the API, It works perfectly on its own but when I add it to the code it works very very very intermittently, sometimes its there sometimes its not and sometimes its half there and only shows fully when refreshed .

I have included the main parts of the code below that relate to this section of the project help would be appreciated.

This is a reduced form of the HTML

```
 <html lang ="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="en" http-equiv="content-language">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        </head>
<body>
    <div data-role ='page' id = "Archaeology"  data-theme ="b" > 

        <header data-role = "header">
            <h1>The National Museum of Archaeology</h1>
            <a href='#Museums' data-icon = 'back'>Back</a>
        </header>

        <p>The national repository for all archaeological objects found in Ireland and home to over two million artefacts. </p>

        <div data-role="content" >
            <div id="container">    
                <img src="ARchBackground.jpg" style= "height:100%; width: 100%;"/>
            </div>
        </div>



        <ul data-role = "listview">

            <li>
            </li>

            <li>
            </li>

            <li>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#Archmap_page" data-theme="" id="arch_gmap"> <img src="arch.gif" width="150" height="150" rel="external" > <br/> Find us on google maps </a>
            </li>

        </ul

        <div data-role="page" id="Archmap_page">
    <header data-role = "header">
        <h1>The National Museum of Archaeology</h1>
        <a href='#Archaeology' data-icon = 'back'>Back</a>
    </header>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height:200px; width: 500px;"></div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="from">From</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="from" value="Enter your location here"/>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="to">To</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="to" value="The National Museum of Ireland, Archaeology "/>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="mode" class="select">Transportation method:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-0" id="mode">
                        <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
                        <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
                        <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <a data-icon="search" data-role="button" href="#" id="submit">Get directions</a>
            </div>
            <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                <div id="directions"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the javscript

```
        $(document).delegate('#Archmap_page', 'pageinit', function () {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            calculateRoute();
        });

        var directionDisplay,
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            map;

        function initialize() 
        {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(53.340617, -6.255244);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom:30,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: mapCenter
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));  
        }

        function calculateRoute() 
        {
            var selectedMode = $("#mode").val(),
                start = $("#from").val(),
                end = $("#to").val();

            if(start == '' || end == '')
            {
                // cannot calculate route
                $("#results").hide();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var request = {
                    origin:start, 
                    destination:end,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[selectedMode]
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                        $("#results").show();
                        /*
                            var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                            for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                            }
                        */
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#results").hide();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    </script>
```

I have seen solutions that advise adding things like `rel="external"` in the anchor tags linking to a page with a google map. Can anyone shed some light on this I know its been asked before, but I wouldn't describe myself as good as javascript its more just a copy and paste job for me here.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you call `initialize()` using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);`? Why not just `initialize()`?

Comment: I do I accidentally left that in from one of the  attempts i was making to fix the problem, it should read `initialize()`. In anycase that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You should call it on `pageshow` when content div height is defined. Here's a similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696717/is-there-a-way-to-preload-google-map-with-jquery-mobile/21779195#21779195 and more here http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/preload-google-maps-jquery-mobile/

Comment: THAAAAANK YOU! add and I will accept as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common difficulty most of developers face when using jQuery Mobile and Google Maps. jQuery Mobile is based on *Ajax* navigation to load, render and show pages. Unlike HTTP, where all elements are loaded and shown at once.

A page in jQuery Mobile passes through several *page* events, it starts with `pagebeforecreate` and ends with `pageshow` -*`pagechange` is last but rarely used*-. During those events, a *page* gets enhanced/rendered but still not fully ready to be shown, as *height* of main divs is still unset.

However, on `pageshow` *height* of main divs is set and defined, except for content div `data-role="content"` which depends on elements within.

This being said, *initializing* Google Maps should occur during `pageshow` event. Using any other event will load an incomplete map. Another note, *height* of content div should be reset in order to fully accommodate map. I have written in details a [full solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553307/1771795) for all jQuery Mobile versions.

**CSS** - Remove content's div `padding` and set map's div `height` and `width`.

```
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui-content {
  padding: 0;
}
```

**JS** - Initialize map on `pageshow` event. If it's a full page map (no toolbars), reset content div's `height` and `width` based on *viewport*. Remember that content div's dimensions should be reset on `orientationchange` and `throttledresize` events.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#mapPage", function () {
  $(".ui-content", this).css({
    height: $(window).height(),
    width: $(window).width()
  });
  InitilizeMap();
});
```

You can also use `.one()` instead of `.on()` if you want to initialize it one time only.

**Bonus** - Back button for full page map, to be appended on `idle` event after map is fully initialized.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function (e) {
    $("#map-canvas").append($("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-rel='back' class='forMap'>Back</a>").hide().fadeIn(300));
    $(".forMap").buttonMarkup({
        mini: true,
        inline: true,
        corners: false
    });
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function (e) {
    $(".forMap").animate({
        "opacity": 0.3
    }, 300);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function (e) {
    $(".forMap").animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 700);
});
```

Back button CSS

```
.forMap {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/THP76/)**

---

**References:**

- jQuery Mobile 1.2 events - [`pageshow`](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html)
- Preload Google Maps - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21779195/1771795) / [Blog](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/preload-google-maps-jquery-mobile/)
- Content div dimensions - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553307/1771795) / [Blog](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/)
- Google Maps Events - [`idle` / `dragstart` / `dragend`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)