# Load Map JQuery Mobile 1.4.3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I want to load a map into a div but im cant make it work (map is not loading) using 1.4.3 jquery mobile version.

Everything is working under jquery mobile 1.1.0, but not with 1.4.3.

I was reading some other posts in stackoverflow forum related with new versions of jquery mobile specification, but i didnt manage to make it work.

Javascript (working with v. 1.1.0):

> $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
>               $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
>           });
>
> ```
>     $(Start);
>
>     function Start() {
>         $(".ui-collapsible-heading").live("click", function () {
>             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.945334, -75.168041);
>             var myOptions = {zoom: 8, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
>             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
>             google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
>                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});
>
>                 alert(event.latLng);
>             });
>         });
>     }
> ```

How can i modify my code in order to accomplish the same result using Jquery Mobile 1.4.3 ?

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, use `.on`.

Comment: @Omar i tried but the same is happening. I can see the map after a refresh but not when i came from another page.

Comment: Because you need to use pagecontainer events http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/ another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997604/jquery-mobile-google-maps-showing-intermittently/22001257#22001257

Comment: i was trying all day make it work and nothing. I already read about it, but still dont know whats wrong. The second link has a similar example but i cant make it work on my project.

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle?

Comment: @Omar http://jsfiddle.net/xpto_dc/kt8Zf/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57351/discussion-between-omar-and-user1907954).