# jquery-ui-map with new version of jquery mobile and jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova, google-maps, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-map

I am upgrading an old **hybrid application** with the latest versions of *jQuery (1.7 -> 2.2.4)* and *jQuery Mobile (1.1 -> 1.4.5)*.
This app contains a page with a **map** created with **jquery-ui-map**.
Now I'm testing the app with **PhoneGap** and the page containing the map is empty, do not show anything and there aren't errors to the console.
In all the examples that I found on the internet, they are used previous versions of jquery.
1. jquery-ui-map can also be used for the latest versions of jquery?
2. Could be a problem of Phonegap? If I create an apk, I can see the map?
3. Is better if I use another code to create a map?
Here's the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pagecreate',function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
},500);     
});


$(function(){

$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: '',
    textVisible: false,
    theme: 'a',
    html: ""
});

$('#map-canvas').gmap({'center':'1111,0000','zoom':10}).on('init',function(){ // coordinates example
    var Link = "http://google.com"; // Example
    $.getJSON(link, function(data){
        ....
    }); 

});

});
</script>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: JQM isn't compatible with jQuery 3.x

Comment: Which version is compatible? On the official website, there is only 3.x version, is it correct?

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery/ use 1.9 or 2.x

Comment: Thank you, now I have changed the version of jquery but the problem isn't solved.

Comment: load map on `pagecontainershow` event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997604/jquery-mobile-google-maps-showing-intermittently/22001257#22001257

Comment: Preload google map: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21779195/1771795

Comment: Thank you Omar but I would like to use gmap, is it possible? Or is better if I use Google Maps code? If I use Google maps I must to change a lot of code in my app. Anyway, I've tried your example and from browser it works, but with Phonegap I don't see the map. It doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Same concept, run gmap code on `pagecontainershow`. give map canvas height and width. I don't know about phonegap.

Comment: Solved! 1. I use your function "canvasHeight" 2. I replaced the function "bind" width "one" to initialize the map. But there is a small problem.. with Phonegap show "We are sorry, there are no images available for this region". Do you know something about this error?

Comment: Good! don't forget to post an answer. I'm not experienced in phonegap, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
1. Use function **canvasHeight** written by Omar before map's loading ([Is there a way to preload google map with jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696717/is-there-a-way-to-preload-google-map-with-jquery-mobile/21779195#21779195))
2. Replace function **bind** with **one** to initialize the map.
Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pagecreate',function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
     $.mobile.loading('hide');
 },500);     
});


$(function(){

 $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: '',
    textVisible: false,
    theme: 'a',
    html: ""
 });

 canvasHeight("#map-canvas");

 $('#map-canvas').gmap({'center':'1111,0000','zoom':10}).one('init',function(){ // coordinates example
var Link = "http://google.com"; // Example
  $.getJSON(link, function(data){
    ....
  }); 

 });

});

function canvasHeight(canvas) {
var canvasPage = $(canvas).closest("[data-role=page]").length !== 0 ? $(canvas).closest("[data-role=page]") : $(".ui-page").first(),
    screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
    header = $(".ui-header", canvasPage).hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header", canvasPage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header", canvasPage).outerHeight(),
    footer = $(".ui-footer", canvasPage).hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer", canvasPage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer", canvasPage).outerHeight(),
    newHeight = screen - header - footer;
$(canvas).height(newHeight);
$(canvas).width($(window).width());
}
</script>
```

Thanks Omar :)